# Hover button not working correctly

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to change my text in my button to white when I hover over it. However when I hover over my button the text colour does not change to white but to a gray colour but the background changes to the correct colour which implies that I'm hovering over the correct element. I inspected this and it seems the `button:hover` is being overridden by an existing text hover colour. Is there any way that I can remove the current gray hover colour and use my white hover colour?

My code is as fallows

```css
.button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #1B43F9;
}
```

```html
 <a class="button" href="#">Buy Now</a>
</ul>
```

my whole css is as fallows

```
.columns {
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Style the list */

.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7%;
}

/* Add shadows on hover */

.price:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .columns {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Pricing header */

.price .header {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 36px 36px 0px 0px;
}

/* List items */

.price li {
  margin-left: 4%;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Grey list item */

.price .annualPrice {
  background-color: #1BA5E0;
  margin: 0px;
  font-style: bold;
  color: white;
  height: 75px;
}

.subTitle {
  background-color: #1BA5E0;
  padding: 3%;
  color: white;
}

/* The "Sign Up" button */

.button {
  background-color: #1ba5e0;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.button:hover {

  background-color: #1B43F9;
}

/* Change the width of the three columns to 100% 
(to stack horizontally on small screens) */

.header {
  margin-bottom: 8.5%;
}

.price li {
  background: url(http://presentationsolutions.eu/new2/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/check.png) no-repeat left top;
  height: 10%px;
  padding-left: 14%;
  padding-top: 0%;
  text-align: left;
}

.buyCompareButton {
  margin: 12% 0% 8% 0%;
  font-family: "myriad-pro","myriad-pro",sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 300!important;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 28px !important;
}
```

Comment: When you created your [MCVE] you failed to check if it actually demonstrated the problem. It doesn't.

Comment: @Quentin The snippet works fine but it doesn't work on my website and I was simply asking if there was something I was doing wrong.

Comment: if it is not working on your website, you need to show your web page, there will be some other css class is blocking this css

Comment: Obviously you are doing *something* wrong, but how do you expect us to tell you what it is when you haven't shown us that code that causes the problem?

Comment: I honestly am not sure what to show you as I'm not sure where is issue is lying

Comment: I'm using Wordpress with a plugin that enables me to view and edit the css do I don't have dev tools

Comment: your code is work fine ...what is issue ??

Comment: @Sumitpatel I'm creating an website in WordPress and have a plugin where I can edit the css. My issue is my font color is not changing to white when I hover over it. I inspected the element in google chrome and found that the font color is changing to color:#447490; and I can't seem to override this. Any ideas on how I would be able to change it to white;

Comment: I figured it out all I needed was `color:white !important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem could be that your Website uses different stylesheets.

Try to write !important behind your color.

Your css code:

```
.button:hover {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #1B43F9;
}
```